# How to Convert a string without any delimiter to a comma delimited string?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have a file details.txt in which data stored is in this format

```
        "571955NandhithaF1975-12-222011-12-06Mumbai"
```

Columns are first six digit unique id ,
 name , (M/F) Gender , dob,joining date , and location 
i have to separate this in six columns using comma delimiter !!
Please help me in this problem

Comment: I don't see comma from your file snippet. What have you achieved so far using Mapreduce?

Comment: @waltersu he wants to generate a string which is comma delimited.

Comment: @JimHawkins   exactly,u got my point. i have to process this comma delimited data in map reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Pass each line into a regex function which contains the below logic :

```
    String expression = "571955NandhithaF1975-12-222011-12-06Mumbai";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("([0-9]{6})([a-zA-Z]+)([M|F])([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        //System.out.println(matcher.group());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
    }
```

output:

```
571955
Nandhitha
F
1975-12-22
2011-12-06
Mumbai
```

Answer (score 0):

`571955NandhithaF1975-12-222011-12-06Mumbai`

To split this type of data, we have to use **String** Functions in java in the ***mapper*** class under ***map*** method.
You can use `substring(beginindex,endindex)` method to get Id of from the string, its 
like `string id[6]=substring(0,5)` which returns 6 digit string that is ID.(As ID is Fixed length we take 6)

You can use `substring(beginindex)` to get remaining string.

Next on wards you have to use  **REGXP** in java..  along with `split(regexp)` to get the name, gender, dob, doj, loc.
 But definitely some workout with java takes place.

go through [this link for String functions in java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

*Hope this post may help.
If any suggestions or modifications to the same are also accepted :)*